# React-bootstrap Modal component opens/closes all modals when I map through a list

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap

New to programming so I'm sorry if I'm not wording this correctly. I'm using a .map to render and list every single item on an array. For each item, I want the modal to open/close only the specific modal corresponding to each item in the array. However, when I click on the button to open the modal, every single one opens and closes. I believe this is because the modals are all set to an on/off button together. How can I set it it (with the .map value.id or something) so that only the specific modal opens and closes?

```
class DrinkMenu extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            show: false
        };
        this.handleHide = this.handleHide.bind(this);
    }

    handleHide() {
        this.setState({ show: false });
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        let res = await axios.get('/getAllDrinks')
        this.props.updateDrinkMenu(res.data)
    }

    async addToCart(drinkObj) {
        let res = await axios.post('/addToCart', drinkObj)
        console.log(`Added ${drinkObj.name} to order.`)
    }

    render() {
        let drinkList = this.props.drinkMenu.map((drink) => {
            return (
                <div key={drink.id}>
                    <h5>{drink.name}</h5>
                    <h6>${drink.price}</h6>

                    <span
                        onClick={() => this.setState({ show: true })}
                    >
                        <strong>More Info</strong>
                        <br />
                        <button onClick={() => this.addToCart(drink)}>Add to Order</button>

                    </span>

                    <Modal
                        show={this.state.show}
                        onHide={this.handleHide}
                        container={this}
                        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title"
                    >
                        <Modal.Header closeButton>
                            <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title">
                                {drink.name}
                            </Modal.Title>
                        </Modal.Header>
                        <Modal.Body>
                            <p>{drink.sub_category} | ABV {drink.abv}% | {drink.origin}</p>
                            <Col xs={6} md={4}>
                                <Image className="drink-logo" src={drink.logo} thumbnail />
                            </Col>
                            <p className="drink-description"><strong>Description</strong><br />{drink.description}</p>
                            <p href={drink.website}>Website</p>
                        </Modal.Body>
                        <Modal.Footer>
                            <Button onClick={this.handleHide}>Close</Button>
                        </Modal.Footer>
                    </Modal>
                </div>
            )
        })

        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Drink Menu</h2>
                <div>
                    {drinkList}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the code you have shared, I see that you are handling all the `Model` with the same state value, i.e. `show`. This is causing all the state for all the `Models` to be `true` hence all of them as shown.

To solve this, you can extract your whole component in a new `React` class which has just the functionality to show `Modal` as per the independent state. So your new React component will look something like this:

```
class DrinkComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleHide = this.handleHide.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            show: false,
        }
    }
    handleHide() {
        this.setState({ show: false });
    }
    render() {
        const { drink } = this.props;
        return (<div key={drink.id}>
            <h5>{drink.name}</h5>
            <h6>${drink.price}</h6>
            <span
                onClick={() => this.setState({ show: true })}
            >
                <strong>More Info</strong>
                <br />
                <button onClick={() => this.props.addToCart(drink)}>Add to Order</button>
            </span>
            <Modal
                show={this.state.show}
                onHide={this.handleHide}
                container={this}
                aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title"
            >
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title">
                        {drink.name}
                    </Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <p>{drink.sub_category} | ABV {drink.abv}% | {drink.origin}</p>
                    <Col xs={6} md={4}>
                        <Image className="drink-logo" src={drink.logo} thumbnail />
                    </Col>
                    <p className="drink-description"><strong>Description</strong><br />{drink.description}</p>
                    <p href={drink.website}>Website</p>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button onClick={this.handleHide}>Close</Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </div>);
    }
}
```

In this case, each `DrinkComponent` will have its independent state of showing and hiding of the model. Now we have to just modify your existing `render` function in `DrinkMenu`, to display `DrinkComponent`. So your `render` function will look something like this:

```
render() {
        let drinkList = this.props.drinkMenu.map((drink) => (<DrinkComponent drink={drink} addToCart={this.addToCart}/>));
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Drink Menu</h2>
                <div>
                    {drinkList}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Also you can remove the show `state` from `DrinkMenu` as it wont be needed there.
Hope it helps.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much! Really appreciate your help!

Comment: @JustinC. A side note about your `componentDidMount`... it probably shouldn't be asynchronous, but since axios returns promises, they are 'then'-able.

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/getAllDrinks')
            .then(function(res) {
                this.props.updateDrinkMenu(res.data);
            });
    }

As a second aside, it's odd that this component is calling out to update the drink menus it is also rendering from props.  It's typically calculated by a parent component and then passed as you've done.

Comment: @JustinC please accept the answer in case it has resolved the issue

Comment: @DrewReese Hi Drew. Between using async/await, or just the .then, is there one method that is better than the other, or considered a better practice? In regards to the updateDrinkMenus, I'm also using Redux, and this is updating the Redux state so I can map through all of the data and display it. Once again I'm not sure if I'm doing this the best way, so if you have any tips, that would be appreciated!

Comment: @JustinC. Functionally async/await and promises are two different things, but commonly work together.  The key aspect to note here is that the javascript thread will pause at the `await` until that line finishes executing before continuing within that function.  With the promise however, the resolution/rejection is put into a queue to be asynchronously executed later, so the rest of the function executes.  In this case with react, you don't want to needlessly pause its lifecycle functions.

Comment: Updating redux state should happen when the app loads, or when the parent container is getting ready to render the list.  The parent should be responsible for getting the up-to-date drink options, then pass those to the list through a `mapStateToProps` redux function.

Comment: @PranayTripathi My drinkList currently maps through the entire list of drinks that I have in my database. If I wanted the option to break it down into sub-categories, how could I go about doing this? I currently have something like:

render() {
        let lagers = this.props.drinkMenu.filter(drink => drink.category === 'lagers').map((drink) => (<DrinkComponent drink={drink} addToCart={this.addToCart}/>));
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Lagers</h2>
                <div>
                    {lagers}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

Comment: @PranayTripathi However, I have about 12 different subcategories, so breaking it down like this would end up being a bit repetitive and not "DRY". Do you have any recommendations for better ways to approach this? For reference, I'm trying to create something like this: https://www.yardhouse.com/menu-listing/beer

Comment: well I dont see the logic changing until you change the structure of the data.