# How to properly set state to allow React Bootstrap Modal to work on mapped data?

Tags: bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap, use-state, bootstrap-5, dry

Trying to build a D.R.Y. list of vocabulary terms with React Bootstrap (v.2.2.3) using Bootstrap 5.1.

I bring in my data:

```
import vocData from '../data/vocData'
```

My component:

```
const VocList = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false)

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false)

  return (
    <ul className="list-inline">
      {Object.keys(vocData).map((item, key) => (
        <React.Fragment key={key}>
          <li className="list-inline-item voc-item">
            <Button>
              <small>{vocData[item].title}</small>
            </Button>
          </li>

          <Modal
            show={show}
            onHide={handleClose}
            backdrop="static"
            keyboard={false}
            aria-labelledby={`contained-modal-title-${vocData[item].href}`}
            centered
          >
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title id={`contained-modal-title-${vocData[item].href}`}>
                {vocData[item].title}
              </Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>{vocData[item].content}</Modal.Body>
          </Modal>
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

I can see my list of vocabulary terms is working but my modal is not appearing when I click the button. I've tried to research and read through:

- [React-Bootstrap Multiple Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060594/react-bootstrap-multiple-modal)
- [React-bootstrap Modal component opens/closes all modals when I map through a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422368/react-bootstrap-modal-component-opens-closes-all-modals-when-i-map-through-a-lis)
- [How do I get my react app to display object information in my bootstrap modal when they click on a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67733435/how-do-i-get-my-react-app-to-display-object-information-in-my-bootstrap-modal-wh)
- [How to use React-Bootstrap modals inside a map array method to display AJAX data on button click in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67733435/how-do-i-get-my-react-app-to-display-object-information-in-my-bootstrap-modal-wh)
- [how to show react bootstrap modal inside the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66741055/how-to-show-react-bootstrap-modal-inside-the-function)

but I'm unable to find an answer.

How can I dynamically setState and be able to render my modal for that vocabulary term in my list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `Modal` only once and not render it many times. You can show only one `Modal` at time anyway. I have created a subcomponent for clarity.

There are many ways how to play with state. Here the initial state is `null` and hides the modal. When we click on button we set state with one vocData entry. This also toggles the visibility of `Modal`.

Finally, when we close its again, we set our state to `null`. In this way we use one state for two purposes - control vision and rendering of `Modal` and holding data for it.

[image: Sandbox]